# integer datatype not work in linq to sql

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, crystal-reports

Dear Freinds
            I face a problem that if i make a datattype in sql server of Integer and then use it in linq to sql query it give error of "specific cast not valid" and when i change datatype into varchar the linq to sql query work fine

one more thing how to use linq to sql query to make crystal report

Comment: Can you include a code sample in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it cannot cast the system.integer type. Try the System.int32 type instead, which converts to sql int during [linq sql type mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx#NumericMapping).

Answer (score 0):

```
'Dim addvou As New vr_detail With {.ac_no = DataGridView1.Rows(abcd).Cells(0).Value, .name = DataGridView1.Rows(abcd).Cells(1).Value, .credit = DataGridView1.Rows(abcd).Cells(3).Value, .cust_no = TextBox9.Text, .debit = DataGridView1.Rows(abcd).Cells(2).Value, .vend_no = TextBox2.Text, .vr_date = DateTimePicker1.Text, .vr_no = TextBox1.Text, .post_date = DateTimePicker3.Text, .vr_type = ComboBox1.Text, .sub_ac = DataGridView1.Rows(abcd).Cells(4).Value, .head_ac = DataGridView1.Rows(abcd).Cells(5).Value, .main_ac = DataGridView1.Rows(abcd).Cells(6).Value}

            voucher.vr_details.InsertOnSubmit(addvou)
            voucher.SubmitChanges()'
```